# setting and getting data in textarea using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have  a textarea on a page that I update and set the data in using ajax, but for some reason line breaks are represented by a `\n`. I've tried server side changing them and client side but no matter what I do I either get a `\n` in the textarea or a `<br />` tag in there.

I have tried using `.val()`, `.text()` and `.html()` to get and set the info.

Any help really appreciated

Thanks

Sorry the code I am using

to update using ajax

```
var genNotes = $('#MainContent_TxtGenNotes').val();
var param = { notes: genNotes } 
 $.ajax({
    url: "default.aspx/UpdateInfo",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    etc etc
```

the code I'm using to retrieve

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "default.aspx/UserDetails",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
    success: function (data) {
        try {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        var json_obj = $.parseJSON(json);
        $('#MainContent_TxtGenNotes').html(json_obj[0].genNotes);
        etc etc
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: As well as the code, seeing your data you're trying to set as the textarea value would help - I'm guessing it's encoded somehow.

Comment: Use `.val()`, then make sure all `\n` only have a single backward slash. You can use `replace` to replace all `\\n`or`\\\n` with just a single slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the character escaping in the ajax process. Make sure you replace `\\n` with `\n` from your ajax response.

You may try `ajaxResponse.replace(/\\+n/g,"\n")`;

Comment: I think your absolutely right with that. That seems to have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the data using .html().

eg.

`<textarea id="area1"></textarea>`

```
$("#area1").html("1\n2");
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ms7q9srd/)

Comment: Yes I can read. But using .html() is the way to achieve this.

Comment: So if it didn't work for the OP, why is it now suddenly going to work?

Comment: Well I suppose without seeing his code we'll never know.